# How to pass and access arguements to pyspark job submit from console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently we have sample.py file on google storage and we need to pass arguements to this script from console.

```
#sample.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import sys


reg = (sys.argv[1])
month = (sys.argv[2])
current_date = (sys.argv[3])
```

And we are trying to submit job using the following command:-

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --project=my_project --cluster=my_cluster --region=region_1 gs://shashi/python-scripts/sample.py abc 11 2019-12-05
```

And it gives the following error:-

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) argument --properties: Bad syntax for dict arg: [spark.driver.memory]. Please see `gcloud topic flags-file` or `gcloud topic escaping` for information on providing list or dictionary flag values with special characters.
Usage: gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark PY_FILE --cluster=CLUSTER [optional flags] [-- JOB_ARGS ...]
  optional flags may be  --archives | --async | --bucket | --driver-log-levels |
                         --files | --help | --jars | --labels |
                         --max-failures-per-hour | --properties | --py-files |
                         --region
```

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to include `--` before arguments

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --project=my_project --cluster=my_cluster --region=region_1 gs://shashi/python-scripts/sample.py -- abc 11 2019-12-05
```